# Append Elements from array AB to every element in array A

Tags: swift

I have two arrays I would like to append the elements of array B (times) to every element in array A (dates) to create a new Array

[String:[String]]

I would like the output to be

["10/20/19": ["8:00 AM - 10:00 AM","10:00 AM -12:00 PM","12:00 PM - 2:00 PM"],"10/21/19": ["8:00 AM - 10:00 AM","10:00 AM -12:00 PM","12:00 PM - 2:00 PM"]]

```
import UIKit

var deliveryDates: [String] = []
var deliveryTimes: [String] = []

deliveryDates = ["10/20/19","10/21/19"]
deliveryTimes = ["8:00 AM - 10:00 AM","10:00 AM -12:00 PM","12:00 PM - 2:00 PM"]

var deliveryWindows: [String: [String]] = [:]


func createDeliverySlots(dDates: [String], dtimes: [String]){

    var ddeliveryWindows: [String: [String]] = [:]

    let ddtimes:[String] = dtimes
    var dddates:[String] = dDates

    for _ in dddates{
     dddates.append("\(ddtimes)")

    }

   print(dddates)


}

createDeliverySlots(dDates: deliveryDates, dtimes: deliveryTimes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the `deliveryDates` array with `deliveryTimes` array and then reduce it to your desired result:

```
var deliveryWindows: [String: [String]] = [:]
deliveryWindows = deliveryDates.map({ [$0: deliveryTimes]}).flatMap({ $0 }).reduce([:], { ( dict, tuple) in
    var tempDict = dict
    tempDict[tuple.0] = tuple.1
    return tempDict
})
```